# Maven run from bash script ignoring profile?

Tags: java, bash, maven

I wrote a little script to compile the test version of a .jar and put it out on my test server.

```
cd /home/myusername/workspace/td-daily-budget
mvn -P test clean compile package
scp /home/myusername/workspace/td-daily-budget/target/td-daily-budget-1.0.jar myusername@666.666.666.666:/home/myusername/bin/td-daily-budget.jar
```

When I run it I get a jar file whose config.properties contains things like

db.connect.string=${db.connect.string}

but when I run **mvn -P test clean compile package** all by itself in the terminal window I get a jar file put together with the **test** profile, e.g. config.properties contains **db.connect.string=[what I expect it to be for the dev profile]**. Why does the same command ignore the profile when run inside a script?

Thanks in advance!

[edit/addendum]

Tried changing the script line to 
**/bin/bash mvn -P env-test clean package**
(it's bash, not Windows, so there's no **call**  command, but using bash to call another script seems to make sense to me) but just got

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
**

I think calling it as an external process mucks up Maven's understanding of where it's supposed to be executing.

[2nd edit/addendum]

Removed the redundant **compile** from the command.

It now appears that this is actually an intermittent problem. The filtering **almost** always fails when **mvn -P [pretty much ANY profile] clean package** runs from inside the bash script, but if I run it standalone from the command line repeatedly it will work eight or nine times and then fail several times in a row. I cannot find any pattern to this at all.

As soon as I discovered this I thought I knew the culprit: The m2e plugin for Eclipse was "helping" me in the background every time it saw files changing. So I excitedly shutdown Eclipse thinking the problem would vanish instantly, ran **mvn -P env-test clean compile package** several times in a row--it worked the first few times and then failed. /headdesk

[edit/addendum]

Removed the space between the **-P** and the profile name. Still no luck.

Comment: To call `mvn compile package` does not make sense, cause if you call `mvn package` includes the `compile` life cycle phase. Best is that you show the full pom file. I assume you have some problems with your profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the mvn in your batch with "call" command, so sth like:

```
call mvn -P test clean compile package
```

The reason is, that mvn is a batch file itself and thus needs to be invoked with "call".

Please give it a try!

Bluddy

Comment: Assuming you meant a batch file of course. But now that I see you talk about "bash", you probably mean a sh script, right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to have a profile with the same name as a phase?  Try renaming your "test" profile to "env-test" and use:

```
mvn -P env-test clean package
```

EDIT:

If you believe it has to do with calling it from a script, try adding a bash declaration at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/myusername/workspace/td-daily-budget
mvn -P env-test clean package
scp /home/myusername/workspace/td-daily-budget/target/td-daily-budget-1.0.jar myusername@666.666.666.666:/home/myusername/bin/td-daily-budget.jar
```

Credit Bluddymarri for suggesting the batch script equivalent.

Comment: To call `mvn compile package` does not make sense, cause if you call `mvn package` includes the compile life cycle phase.

Comment: @khmarbaise True, but I doubt it has anything to do with his issue.  Edited the `mvn` lines to remove `compile`, anyway.